# Inverting mouse axis using Karabiner

Tags: mouse, macos

Karabiner seems like an extremely versatile piece of software, but I can't seem to find a way to invert the mouse axis with it. For example: When I move the mouse downwards I want the cursor to go upwards, and when I move the mouse to the right, I want the cursor to go left.<sup>(*)</sup>

Right now I'm using [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com) for this purpose, but I need Karabiner for other stuff, and it would be nice if I could get away with just one program.

<sup>(*) This sounds so strange that I feel I owe you an explanation: I have a trackball mouse which, due to it's form factor forces me to turn it 180 degrees on my desk. By inverting the axis in software, it still moves naturally.</sup>

Comment: Karabiner lets you modify how your keyboard, keys, keyboard layouts, and key combinations behave. It is not designed to modify the mouse.

Comment: @timothymh Wrong! it works after some investigation!

Comment: Why the downvote? I've done a lot of research before posting, the question is clear, judging from other questions and meta-discussions it seems on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flip cursor movement you can use a third party tool: Karabiner. Karabiner isn't compatible with Sierra at the time of writing (January 2017).

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH8pi.png)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
       <name>3rd-Party Pointing Device</name>
       <item>
           <name>Reverse Vertical &amp; Horizontal Cursor Movement</name>
           <identifier>reverse.mouse.movement</identifier>
           <autogen>
             __FlipPointingRelative__
             Option::FLIPPOINTINGRELATIVE_HORIZONTAL,
             Option::FLIPPOINTINGRELATIVE_VERTICAL,
           </autogen>
       </item>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```

   If you already have other items in private.xml omit the first two and the last line of the above code.
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

[image]

---

If you have a second pointing device (i.e. an Apple mouse or a trackpad) and want to use it normally, you have to restrict the *mod* to your trackball mouse by adding a devicevendordef/deviceproductdef somewhere and a device tag after the identifier tag in your private.xml. Example (sorry, only an Apple external keyboard):

```
<devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>Apple</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x05ac</vendorid>
</devicevendordef>
<deviceproductdef>
    <productname>ExternalKeyboard</productname>
    <productid>0x0256</productid>
</deviceproductdef>
...
<device_only>DeviceVendor::Apple, DeviceProduct::ExternalKeyboard</device_only>
```

You get the various device IDs by opening Karabiner > Misc. & Uninstall > EventViewer > Devices

Comment: Amazing. You found it. Precisely what I was looking for. Tested it and confirmed that it works.

Comment: Does someone know how to do this in more recent versions of karabiner which is configured using json format?

Comment: Seems not to be a way to configure it on new versions. This question has been also pointed on its github project with no response: https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2440